# ReferenceError: exports is not defined error in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-datepicker

I am seeing the following error with react-datetime-picker v3.5.0 and Next.js.

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Call Stack
eval
node_modules/react-datetime-picker/dist/DateTimePicker.js (8:0)
./node_modules/react-datetime-picker/dist/DateTimePicker.js
...
/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js (718:31)
```

In `next.config.js` I have:

```
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['react-datetime-picker']); // pass the modules you would like to see transpiled
module.exports = withTM(nextConfig)
```

Comment: What Next.js version are you using? Looks related to this GitHub issue https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/38117, seems to have been introduced in the 12.2.0 release. Try downgrading `next` for now.

Comment: Yes. I was using 12.2.0. Thank you for sharing the issue link.

Comment: I am getting this on 14.04 if anyone comes across a recent solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks related to a bug introduced in the v12.2.0 release. See related GitHub issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/38117.

You should downgrade Next.js to v12.1.6 for now.